# How to make ToggleButton Active 1 at a time(flutter)

Tags: flutter

So I have this toggle buttons and I just want user to select toggle buttons one at a time.

I currently studying flutter.

Here's the code.

```
ToggleButtons(
   borderColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(0),
                                   borderRadius:BorderRadius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(50),topRight:Radius.circular(50) ),
    borderWidth: .5,
    selectedBorderColor: BlueSubmerge.withAlpha(0),
    selectedColor: SunGlow.withAlpha(255),
    color: Colors.white,
    renderBorder: true,
    children: <Widget>[
    toggleButton("Sleep", Icons.hotel),
    toggleButton("Eat", Icons.local_dining),
    toggleButton("Relax", Icons.self_improvement),
    toggleButton("Experience", Icons.tour),
    ],
    onPressed: (int index) {
      setState(() {
      _selections[index] = !_selections[index];
   });
   },
   isSelected: _selections,
      ),
```

Comment: Please format your code properly without a starting indentation of 20 kilometers. Also you have put zero effort into your question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm so sorry, hehehe. That is my question, I just want to be straight forward. Am I missing an information? newbie here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following code :

```
ToggleButtons(
      borderColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(50), topRight: Radius.circular(50)),
      borderWidth: .5,
      selectedBorderColor: BlueSubmerge.withAlpha(0),
      selectedColor: SunGlow.withAlpha(255),
      color: Colors.white,
      renderBorder: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        toggleButton("Sleep", Icons.hotel),
        toggleButton("Eat", Icons.local_dining),
        toggleButton("Relax", Icons.self_improvement),
        toggleButton("Experience", Icons.tour),
      ],
      onPressed: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selections=List.filled(_selections. length, false);
          _selections[index]=true;
        });
      },
      isSelected: _selections,
    )
```

Comment: Can you explain it? I just don't want to copy paste it without knowing what is what.

Comment: Just two lines different from your code. First line means fill all selections with false. 
Second line means set the selected index true.  So first line deselects everything, second line sets the selected index to true.

Comment: Wow! I am wayyyyyyy too far from being a "I know flutter". Thank you very much. I just need to keep going.